# getenv() php 7.2 return false

Tags: php, environment-variables, ubuntu-18.04

I try to get env of **ACCOUNT_NAME**  using `getenv()` function in php. And when I try to `var_dump()` it, it return `false`. I've been check it from terminal using `echo $ACCOUNT_NAME` and it show the result. How can I fix this?

I've been try to use `$_ENV['ACCOUNT_NAME']` but still get same result.

Comment: Environment vars aren't global. Just because it is set in an interactive shell is no guarantee it is set in an unrelated process not started by that shell.

Comment: Can you give me some advice about this problem @KurtisRader?

Comment: You need to learn how environment variables work in UNIX. Each process has its own, private, copy of environment vars. When you modify the environment of the current process (e.g., your interactive shell) that does not change the environment of any other process. When a process starts another process it can give that process a copy of its current environment or a completely different environment.  But once that process is running only that process can modify its env vars.